# What is the replacement for R CMD mydir build --binary?

Tags: r

I have run `R CMD mydir build --binary`
It works, BUT it tells me that `--binary` is deprecated. 
So what is the "new" version of `--binary`?

I am using WinXP, Rtools 2.14 and R 2.13.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Soon to be even worse than deprecated.) From the "What's New" page :
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/NEWS

```
 o R CMD build --binary is formally defunct: R CMD INSTALL --build
  has long been the preferred alternative.
```

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to find this type of information is via the `news()` function:

```
newsDB <- news()
news(grepl("--build", Text) & grepl("DEPRECATED", Category), db=newsDB)
# Changes in version 2.13.0:
# 
# DEPRECATED & DEFUNCT
# 
#     o   R CMD build --binary is now formally deprecated: R CMD INSTALL
#   --build has long been the preferred alternative.
```

Comment: 1+ for supplying a search strategy in R.